# Django redirect for specific user

Tags: django, authentication, redirect, view

Can we redirect to a particular app view for a particular user that is logged in using django.contrib.auth.models

redirects did not work
for a specific user can he be redirected to a particular app home page, if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a view:

```
redirect_user = User.objects.get(id=1) (something to identify a user)
if request.user == redirect_user:
    return(whatever you want to redirect to)
else:
    return(where everyone gets directed to)
```

If you wanted this functionality on every view you could look into making a custom decorator.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It solved the problem. Thanks!